# Proof that the sampling distribution of the sample variance from $N(0,1)\sim \chi_{n-1}^2$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, sampling-distribution

[image: is this true?]

Is this true? How to verify it? 
From the definition of chi square I can not judge whether it is chi square.

Comment: You can find the proof [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/174)

Comment: Independence of $X_{i}$ is required

Comment: It is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}$ that follows $\chi_{n-1}^{2}$.

Comment: Updated [link](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/26/26.3) to proof

Answer (score 7):

Let $X_{i}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots n$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.
Then,  the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}\sim \chi_{n-1}^{2}$, (a chi-square distribution with ($n-1$) degrees of freedom).

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}=(n-1)S^{2}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}&=&\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2}}_{\chi_{n}^{2}}-n\bar{X}^{2}\nonumber\\
(n-1)S^{2}&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2}-n\bar{X}^{2}\nonumber\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2}&=& (n-1)S^{2} + n\bar{X}^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now consider,
\begin{align}
X_{i} &\sim N(0,1)\\
\bar{X} &\sim N(0,\frac{1}{n})\\
\frac{\bar{X}}{1/\sqrt{n}} &\sim N(0,1)\\
n\bar{X}^{2} &\sim \chi_{1}^{2}\\
\end{align}
Identifying the distribution of the terms in the earlier equation, it can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\chi_{n}^{2} = (n-1)S^{2}+\chi_{1}^{2}
\end{equation}

By a property of chi-squared distribution, $S^{2}$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent. That is, right hand side of the above equation is sum of two independent random variables. Now consider the moment generating function on both sides. The left hand side random variable being a $\chi_{n}^{2}$ random variable, its MGF is $(1-2t)^{-n/2}$.

Substituting the MGF values and simplifying,

\begin{align}
M_{\chi_{n}^{2}}(t) &= M_{(n-1)S^{2}}(t)\cdot M_{\chi_{1}^{2}}(t)\\
(1-2t)^{-n/2} &= M_{(n-1)S^{2}}(t) \cdot (1-2t)^{-1/2}\\
M_{(n-1)S^{2}}(t) &= (1-2t)^{-n/2} \cdot  (1-2t)^{1/2}\\
M_{(n-1)S^{2}}(t) &= (1-2t)^{-(n-1)/2}
\end{align}
which is the MGF of a $\chi_{n-1}^{2}$ random variable. Hence,
$(n-1)S^{2}\sim\chi_{n-1}^{2}$.

Comment: The independence of $S^2$ and $\bar X$ seems like a critical step. Can you provide any details about that step?

Comment: @littleO you are correct. For details, you may refer to the book *Statistical inference* by Casella and Berger.

Comment: @littleO please have a look at the reference provided by Antoni Parellada in one of the comments above.

Comment: Hmm, the page Antoni Parellada linked to skips the proof that $S^2$ and $\bar X$ are independent. I'll check out Casella and Berger. Thanks!

Comment: @littleO It can be shown using Basu's Theorem.